# Sum all elements having the same index in different lists

Tags: python, list

```
score=[
 ['5.00', '4.30', '2.50', '3.60', '1.30', '5.00'],
 ['80.00', '8.00', '32.00', '13.60', '20.00', '80.00'], 
 ['12.00', '6.00', '7.20', '8.40', '9.60', '12.00'],
 ['3.00', '1.20', '2.04', '1.08', '0.84', '3.00']
]
```

I want

```
a = 5 + 80 + 12 + 3   # add first element of all lists in score
b = 4.3 + 8 + 6 + 1.2   # add second element of all lists in score
c = 2.5 + 32 + 7.2 + 2.04  # etc ...
d = 3.6 + 13.6 + 8.4 + 1.08  # ...
e = 1.3 + 20 + 9.6 + 0.84
f = 5 + 80 + 12 + 3
```

But I don't know how many lists are in `score`, so I can't use `zip()`. How do I sum all elements having the same index in different lists in python?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Add SUM of values of two LISTS into new LIST](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14050824/add-sum-of-values-of-two-lists-into-new-list)

Answer (score 2):

Actually, you can use [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip):

```
>>> map(sum, map(lambda l: map(float, l), zip(*score)))
[100.0, 19.5, 43.74, 26.68, 31.74, 100.0]
```

Answer (score 1):

The best way to do this is using the [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/functions.html#zip) built-in class<sup>1</sup> or function<sup>2</sup> and the [`*-operator`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists) to unpack the "scores" into variables using the a simple assignment operation. You then use the [`sum`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/functions.html?highlight=float#sum) built-in function to calculate the sum. Of course you will need to convert you element to float using [`float`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/functions.html?highlight=float#float) and [`map`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/functions.html?highlight=float#map)

```
>>> score = [
... ['5.00', '4.30', '2.50', '3.60', '1.30', '5.00'],
...  ['80.00', '8.00', '32.00', '13.60', '20.00', '80.00'], 
... ['12.00', '6.00', '7.20', '8.40', '9.60', '12.00'],
...  ['3.00', '1.20', '2.04', '1.08', '0.84', '3.00']
... ]
>>> a, b, c, d, e, f = [sum(map(float, i)) for i in zip(*score)]
>>> a
100.0
>>> b
19.5
>>> c
43.74
>>> d
26.68
>>> e
31.74
>>> f
100.0
```

---

1. Python 3.x
2. Python 2.x

Answer (score 0):

Slightly different way:

```
score = [
    ['5.00', '4.30', '2.50', '3.60', '1.30', '5.00'],
    ['80.00', '8.00', '32.00', '13.60', '20.00', '80.00'], 
    ['12.00', '6.00', '7.20', '8.40', '9.60', '12.00'],
    ['3.00', '1.20', '2.04', '1.08', '0.84', '3.00']
]

def sum_same_elements(l):
    l_float = [map(float, lst) for lst in l]
    to_sum  = []
    for i in range(len(l[0])):
        lst_at_index = []
        for lst in l_float:
            lst_at_index.append(lst[i])
        to_sum.append(lst_at_index)
    return map(sum, to_sum)

print sum_same_elements(score)
```