# Python code to return total count of no. of positions in which items are differing at same index

Tags: python, arrays, python-2.7, python-3.x, numpy

A=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
B=[1,2,3,7,4,6,5,8,9]

I have to compare these two lists and return the count of no. of location in which items are differing using one line python code.

For example: 
the output should be 4 for given arrays because at index (3,4,5,6) the items are differing.So, program should return 4.

My way of doing this is comparing each and every location using for loop:

```
count=0
for i in range(0,len(A)):
   if(A[i]==B[i]):
     continue
   else:
     count+=1
print(count)
```

Please help me in writing one line python code for this.

Comment: @StevenRumbalski Should be `a != b`.

Comment: Correction:  `sum(a != b for a, b in zip(A, B))` (Thanks @acw1668.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
count = sum(a != b for a, b in zip(A, B))
print(count)
```

or just `print sum(a != b for a, b in zip(A, B))`

you can check about [zip/lambda/map here](https://bradmontgomery.net/blog/pythons-zip-map-and-lambda/), those tools are very powerfull and important in python..

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14050824/add-sum-of-values-of-two-lists-into-new-list) you can also check others kind of ways to use those tools.

Have fun!!

Answer (score 1):

There are [many ways](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28663856/how-to-count-the-occurrence-of-certain-item-in-an-ndarray-in-python) to do this. If you're using numpy, you could just use [`np.count_nonzero`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.count_nonzero.html):

```
>>> a = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9])
>>> b = np.array([1, 2, 3, 7, 4, 6, 5, 8, 9])
>>> a != b
array([False, False, False,  True,  True, False,  True, False, False], dtype=bool)
>>> np.count_nonzero(a != b)
3
```

Note that `a != b` returns an *array* containing true and false depending upon how the condition evaluates at each index.

Here's a speed comparison:

```
>>> %timeit np.count_nonzero(a != b)
The slowest run took 40.59 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached.
1000000 loops, best of 3: 752 ns per loop

>>> %timeit sum(i != j for i, j in zip(a, b))
The slowest run took 5.86 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached.
100000 loops, best of 3: 18.5 µs per loop
```

The caching obscures the timing, but `40.59 * 0.752 = 30.52µs`, while `5.86 * 18.5 = 108.41µs`, so numpy's slowest still seems significantly faster than pure python's slowest run.

This is much clearer with larger arrays:

```
>>> n = 10000
>>> a = np.arange(n)
>>> b = np.arange(n)
>>> k = 50
>>> ids = np.random.randint(0, n, k)
>>> a[ids] = 0
>>> ids = np.random.randint(0, n, k)
>>> b[ids] = 0
>>> %timeit np.count_nonzero(a != b)
The slowest run took 20.50 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached.
100000 loops, best of 3: 11.5 µs per loop
>>> %timeit sum(i != j for i, j in zip(a, b))
100 loops, best of 3: 15.6 ms per loop
```

The difference is much more stark, with numpy taking *at most* 235 *micro*-seconds, while pure python takes 15.6 *milli*-seconds on *average*!