# How to add elements in a 2d list to derive one more array?

Tags: python, numpy

My problem statement is I have a 2d list as x = [[1,2,3], [4,5,6]]

I want the out put as [5,7,9]

can somebody help me how can i achieve it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Add SUM of values of two LISTS into new LIST](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14050824/add-sum-of-values-of-two-lists-into-new-list)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will do it:

```
[sum(p) for p in zip(*x)]
```

This produces:

```
[5, 7, 9]
```

Note that this will also work if `x` has more than two sub-lists.