# Python Loop Double Printing

Tags: python, python-2.7, math

Using the code below, I am able to get the correct answer, however it is repeated **twice**.

For instance, I would only want a result of `[1.2038, 1.206]`, but the code below prints `[1.2038, 1.206, 1.2038, 1.206]`. Anybody knows what is wrong with my code? Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

```
spot = [1.2020, 1.2040]
forwardSwap = [0.0018, 0.0020]
forwardOutright = []

for i in range(len(spot)):
    for i in range(len(forwardSwap)):
        forwardOutright.append(spot[i] + forwardSwap[i])

print forwardOutright
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Add SUM of values of two LISTS into new LIST](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14050824/add-sum-of-values-of-two-lists-into-new-list)

Comment: Will spot and forwardSwap always have the same number of elements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to loop over once:

```
spot = [1.2020, 1.2040]
forwardSwap = [0.0018, 0.0020]
forwardOutright = []
for i in range(len(spot)):
    forwardOutright.append(forwardSwap[i]+spot[i])
```

Outout:

```
[1.2038, 1.206]
```

Comment: This only works if both arrays have the same length of items. What if fowardswap only had 1 element?

Answer (score 21):

You should `zip` instead of a nested loop to iterate both lists concurrently:

```
forwardOutright = [x+y for x, y in zip(spot, forwardSwap)]
```

Answer (score 3):

As per the given code in your question, both of your loops are using a variable named as `i`.

```
for i in range(len(spot)):
    for i in range(len(forwardSwap)):
```

Answer (score 3):

This should work

```
list(map(lambda i: sum(i), zip(spot, forwardSwap)))
```

Answer (score 3):

The problem you have is caused by the fact that the inner loop is executed completely every time the outer loop is executed.
i.e for every item in `spot` you are going through every item in `forwardSwap` and appending a new value to `forwardOutright`.
Instead you want a one-to-one matching between these two lists, so you could use:

`for i,j in zip(spot, forwardSwap):
    forwardOutright.append(i+j)`

You should also avoid shadowing your variables, i.e using `i` in both loops, instead you could use `i` and `j` for example. Otherwise this will cause your program to execute in unexpected ways.

Answer (score 1):

Because you have nested `for` loops, the outer loop is run as many times as there are elements of `spot` and the inner loop is run as many times as the product of the lengths. Instead you should use [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/functions.html#zip):

```
for s, fs in zip(spot, forwardSwap):
    forwardOutright.append(s + fs)
```

Or you can use a list comprehension:

```
forwardOutright = [s + fs for s, fs in zip(spot, forwardSwap)]
```

Answer (score 0):

You have two nested loops that run twice each.

Therefore you execute the code inside the second loop (2x2) 4 times.