# Summing up the elements of lists in a for loop

Tags: python, list, for-loop

So the basis of my question is given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14050824/add-sum-of-values-of-two-lists-into-new-list). After all I need to add elements of the lists. In the simplest example:

```
first = [1,2]
second = [6,7]
```

Then

```
[x + y for x, y in zip(first, second)]
```

which gives:

```
#[7,9]
```

However my problem is that I am producing number of lists via a for loop. In the for loop the lists are not being stored and so to see them one uses `print(list)` at the end of the loop and it prints the lists. Now how can I write a code to look at the produced lists and sum the elements in the given manner above?

Example:

```
l = []
for i in range(2):
    l= list(range(5))
    print(l)
```

the above produces:

```
#[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
#[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
```

How can I add a line in the for loop to sum the one-by-one elements of the lists to get:

```
#[0, 2, 4, 6, 8]
```

Comment: Can you provide an example for your question?

Comment: post the code that produces the lists please. This is hard to understand as it is.

Comment: If the lists are only printed and not stored, then you can't use them later.

Comment: I have added an example

Comment: @Will As Aran said, you cannot use what you do not store and in your case, `l` is being overwritten and thus, the old is gone.

Comment: @Aran-Fey How do you store? I have added an example of the problem which would help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a variable to hold the totals, and update it in the loop

```
totals = [0]*5
for i in range(5):
    l = list(range(5))
    totals = [x + y for x, y in zip(totals, l)]
print totals
```

Or you can save all your lists in another list, and then use your original idea:

```
all_lists = []
for i in range(5):
    l = list(range(5))
    all_lists.append(l)
totals = [sum(lists) for lists in zip(*all_lists)]
```

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand, here is another way of doing it i.e. using operator `add`.

```
from operator import add
n=5
l = [0]*n
for i in range(2):
    l = map(add, l, range(n))

print([x for x in l])
```

**Output:**

```
[0, 2, 4, 6, 8]
```